# Flip this android pathdata upside down

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

I found a similar xml file on stack overflow but i don't have much knowledge in android path data.

```
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="8dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFff0000"
        android:pathData="M24 24v-24h-24v24a20 36 0 0 1 24 0z"/>

</vector>
```

This is what i found, but in this the curve is on bottom.
but I need that curve on top.
like the image bellow.

And the white part on the image bellow must be transparent.
Any solution's?
[image: This is what i need]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the path into a group and set the rotation & pivotX,Y attributes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="8dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <group
        android:pivotX="12"
        android:pivotY="12"
        android:rotation="180">
        <path
            android:fillColor="#FFff0000"
            android:pathData="M24 24v-24h-24v24a20 36 0 0 1 24 0z" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

Comment: Oh thanks, its that much simple? I spend the whole last night looking for this solution. The problem is im new to this XML and path data things.. anyway thank you..

Comment: Now i got another problem, Its just stretching when i apply to a wider layout. any way to keep it in aspect ratio

Comment: @JithinAngel'zJas'z Does it stretch in the original vector for the same width?

Comment: @JithinAngel'zJas'z I guess you need to manipulate `android:width` to a larger value